# NHibernate many to many results in many queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am developing a bookmark system in ASP.NET MVC and I use NHibernate to query the database.

I have a many to many relationship:

- A bookmark can have many tags
- A tag can have many bookmarks

Models:

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Link { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get a tag, loop trough its bookmarks, and for each bookmark loop trough its tags. To do this I used this:

```
public Tag GetTagByTitle(string username, string title)
{
    ICriteria criteriaQuery = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
        .CreateCriteria(typeof(Tag))
        .SetFetchMode("Bookmarks", FetchMode.Eager)
        .CreateAlias("User", "User")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Title", title))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("User.Username", username));

    IList<Tag> tags = criteriaQuery.List<Tag>();
    Tag tag = tags.FirstOrDefault();

    return tag;
}
```

This gives me a tag with its bookmarks. However for each bookmark it is doing another query automatically to obtain its tags (lazy loading?). So if I have 10 bookmarks I get 1 + 10 queries. Is it possible to do this with one or two queries?

Example with NHibernate Profiler (3 bookmarks):

[image: Example with NHibernate Profiler (3 bookmarks)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CreateAlias` to eagerly fetch the bookmarks, and it will also allow you to dig another layer deeper to specify how you want to fetch the tags.

```
ICriteria criteriaQuery = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(Tag))
    .CreateAlias("Bookmarks", "b", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .CreateAlias("b.Tags", "bt", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .CreateAlias("User", "User")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Title", title))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("User.Username", username))
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
```

**Edit: Fixed query.**  Sorry about that.  Apparently `SetFetchMode` only works for relationships directly off of the root entity of the query.  Replacing it with `CreateAlias` fixes the issue.

With all of these left-outer-joins to collections, you'll need to modify your entities a bit and update your mappings to prevent duplicate entiries from showing up in the collections.  Instead of `ICollection<T>`, use `ISet<T>` from the `Iesi.Collections.Generic` namespace, and change your mappings to use `<set/>` instead of `<bag/>`.

Comment: This results in almost the same query and doesn't solve the lazy loading for each bookmark.

Comment: This works thank you. I use fluent mapping with AsSet() and this works fine with ICollection<T>. Even though the results are unique, the results in the query are not. So paging will be difficult right?

Comment: Yes, paging will be difficult, but doable.  You'll need to use subqueries or split this into two queries: one query to identify the page of tags to retrieve, the other query to eagerly fetch the other records associated with those tags.